# how to avoid the IIS caused by numerical accuracy issues in Gurobipy, Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

Here is my problem about optimzing a pyomo model by gurobipy:
in some calculus the model will become IIS casused by some very ,very, very small values like

```
x[i] - w[j] <= 0
x[i] = 0.0
w[j] = 3.4456213e-07
```

the value of w[j] is supposed to be 0 in the force of other constraints, yet come to this. I have no idea but I guess the equational constraints may help cause this problem.
Could anyone tell me how to avoid this problem? THX for any help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs in or.stackexchange.com